# How to require('var') with var is local url in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I want to load img in ReactJS. But I can't put url img in require.

[image]

[image]

**Note: const 'Photo' is url link of picture.**

Any help will be appreciated..

Thanks.

Comment: What is the directory structure and what is location of image?

Comment: If `photo` is the url, then there is no need for `require`, just use the constant directly.

Comment: When no need 'require' Its error: Cannot find module '

Comment: [How to dynamic require correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62095265/2873538)

Answer (score 0):

You can [require with expression](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression).

So, this should work:

```
<img src={require('./upload/' + fileName)} />
```

The first part inside require is **directory** and the second one is `fileName` e.g. `my-image.png`.

Or there are various other ways to handle dynamic requires: [map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38397640/2873538), [switch](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391#issuecomment-194581270)

Comment: I tried both of them didn't work.
Anyway photo is really a correct path when I put "./pic.jpg" but string photo="./pic.jpg" is not work

Answer (score 0):

This is the directory structure and 'photo' = "./upload/xxxxxxxxxx.jpg" 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNJ6B.png)