# How do I dynamically import images in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, webpack, dynamic-import

Have seen a couple of answers online but there are no clear explanations and the solutions don't work. So this is what I am trying to do:

- I have a folder of **MANY images** (thousands) - currently it is saved under `src/assets/images` folder
- Given a list of images for example as input, I want to **render these images dynamically**. And not import all because it would be impossible given the insane number of images

This is my current way of implementing it (**which does not work**):

```
// for example
const imageList = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3' /*...so on */]

const getImagePath = (image) => {
  return `../assets/images/${image}.jpg`
}

function ImagesPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <p>Below should show a list of images</p>
      {imageList.map((img) => {
        return <img src={require(getImagePath(img))} />
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

From what I read online, this has something to do with the way **webpack** works, and this will only work if the exact string path is input into the `require`:

```
// This works:
<img src={require('../assets/images/img1.jpg')} />

// But all these will not work:
<img src={require(getImagePath(img))} />

const img = 'img1.jpg'
<img src={require(`../assets/images/${img}`)} />
```

Any idea how I can get this **dynamic importing of images** to work in the scenario I described above? I think this post will be quite helpful to the others searching for an answer too.

Comment: @Daryil Is moving your image folder to public folder an option?

Answer (score 26):

Adding .default will do the trick

```js
<img src={require(`../../folder-path/${dynamic-filename}.png`).default} />
```

#### Update November 2022

After upgrading to **Webpack 5** you will no longer need to append `.default`. In fact, quite the opposite. If you keep it, no image is displayed because no src attibut is added to the image.

```js
<img src={require(`../../folder-path/${dynamic-filename}.png`)} />
```

Comment: This is the approach I went with thanks

Answer (score 5):

**TLDR;**

```
// All of these works

const fileNameExt = 'foo.jpg'
<img src={require('../images/' + fileNameExt)} />
<img src={require(`../images/${fileNameExt}`)} />

const fileName = 'foo'
<img src={require('../images/' + fileName + '.jpg')} />
<img src={require(`../images/${fileName}.jpg`)} />

// These does not work:

const myPathVariable1 = '../images/' + 'foo' + '.jpg'
<img src={require(myPathVariable1)} />

const myPathVariable2 = '../images/' + 'foo.jpg'
<img src={require(myPathVariable2)} />
```

---

You can [require dynamically with expression](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression).

**File names:**

```
const imageList = ["img1", "img2", "img3", ... ]
```

And to render at UI (**add** directory **path** and the **extension** inside `require`):

```
{
  imageList.map(img => {
    return <img src={require("../assets/images/" + img + ".jpg")} />
  })
}
```

**Why it works?:**

Webpack can understand this expression, by [generating context about directory and extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62095265/2873538), and can load all the matching modules.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just for the benefit of others who will read this later on too:
So this expression does not work <img src={require("../assets/images/${img}.jpg")} /> but   this <img src={require("../assets/images/" + img + ".jpg")} /> works?

Comment: @Daryll Yes, as I explained in details - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62095265/2873538, to make dynamic require work, in simple words, we need to provide **an expression** which webpack can break / understand in terms of **directory** (and better if *file extensions* too). Added **TLDR** in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Update your `getImagePath` function to return an `img` element.

```
const getImage = (image) => {
   return <img src={require(`../assets/images/${image}.jpg`)} />
}
```

Then your `map` function would look like this:

```
imageList.map((img) => {
   return getImage(img);
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Saved my day. Worked on this element for almost 1 hour

Answer (score 2):

```
  // for example
const imageList = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3' /*...so on */]

const getImagePath = (image) => {
  return `../assets/images/${image}.jpg`
}

function ImagesPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <p>Below should show a list of images</p>
      {imageList.map((img) => {
        return <img src={require(getImagePath(img)).default} />
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

If you are using "create react app", adding `.default` after `require` works fine, it sets all images dynamically from local image folder.