# How to use variables inside require()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, require

I'm having a problem here and I don't know if it's possible to do this, I'm pulling data as parameters of my route:

```
onPress={() =>
  navigation.navigate('product', {
    pathToImage: "../../images/airdots_category.jpg",
 })
```

Then, I get them on my other page.

```
const pathToImage = route.params.pathToImage;
```

Now, I want to pass the `pathToImage` into the `require()`:

```
<Image source={pathToImage} />
```

But it does not accept, since the path comes correctly, I find it strange because I just put the path inside a variable.

If you have another way of doing it ... please!

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/62192731/2873538

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I dynamically import images in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62192049/how-do-i-dynamically-import-images-in-react)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add require with the image path like this from where you passing your parmas.

```
onPress={() =>
  navigation.navigate('product', {
    pathToImage: require("../../images/airdots_category.jpg"),
 })

const pathToImage = route.params.pathToImage;

<Image source={pathToImage} />
```