# REACT: How do I select an image from assets, to match the component's ID in the "src" attribute of an <img> tag in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

My images files has files named like this:

image1.jpg
image2.jpg
image3.jpg
...
image9.jpg

I have indexed them all and imported them into the component with:

```js
import IMAGES from "../assets/imageIndex";
```

what I would like to do is to match the image, to the component id based on the number at the end of the image file name.

In other words:

```js
<div id={id}>
<img src={IMAGES.image`${id}`;/>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```js
<img src={() => {
let string = "IMAGES.image";
return string.concat(`${id}`);
}}  

response: Warning: Invalid value for prop `src` on <img> tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM
```

I have also tried a separate function:

```js
function selectImage(id)
{
    return `IMAGES.image${id}`;
}   

<div id={id}>
<img src={selectImage(id)} />
</div>
```

But I don't think I am using the correct logic here. Any ideas?

Comment: That might be helpful in your case

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62192049/how-do-i-dynamically-import-images-in-react

Comment: ` <img
              src={
                id <= 9
                  ? require("../assets/images/image-" + id + ".svg").default
                  : require(".../assets/images/image-1.svg").default
              }
              alt="image graphic"
            />