# Lazy loading: Can't load dynamic module

Tags: reactjs, react-lazy-load

I try to load dynamically in my dashboard using `React.lazy()` and `Suspense` component. It works really well with an hardcoded value, but not with a variable. I'm a little bit speechless right now. Probably a dumb error!

Works:

```
const WidgetComponent = React.lazy(() => import('../../../widgets/dummy/Dummy'));
```

Don't works:

```
// widget.path === '../../../widgets/dummy/Dummy'
const WidgetComponent = React.lazy(() => import(widget.path));
```

Don't works also:

```
const WidgetComponent = React.lazy(() => import(`${widget.path}`));
```

One thing I can add is the widget prop is filled from a json file in public folder.

Comment: Using variable would not work. Using an expression should work. [Answer to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62095265/2873538). [Another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62192731/2873538). But I think it is better to write: `React.lazy(() => import('../../../widgets/dummy/Dummy'));`.

Comment: try \`${widget.path}\` instead of widget.path

Comment: Works:

import(`../../../widgets/${widget.component}`));

Don't works:

import(`${widget.path}`));

Comment: \`${widget.path}\` works, check it here https://codesandbox.io/s/reactlazy-forked-1yq4i?file=/src/index.js:259-265

Comment: @ARZMIImad ok I will retry, maybe the compiler who's messing with me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, with the help of @Ajeet Shah I've solved my problem.

I've created a new property with the component name instead and I did that :

```
const WidgetComponent = React.lazy(() => import(`../../../widgets/${widget.component}`));
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it works.